# QGIS Catchment Creation from existing line shapefile (streams)

Tags: qgis, hydrology, catchment-area, catchment

I understand the general process of creating a catchment.

1. Get DEM data Fill sinks
2. Build stream network
3. Create a line shapefile of the stream network
4. Choose outlet location and obtain coordinates
5. Build catchment

That said, the resultant stream network never matches what our government considers the official stream network. That's because it's been edited to fix errors, some glaring. Nature of the algorithms I guess.

So what would be a workflow where watercourse.shp (vector-line) has fields in it for for flow direction and Strahler order? There is no DEM that will generate a close enough match. I need to create a workflow as follows:

1. Choose stream network (vector - line)
2. Choose outlet point (vector - point)
3. Build catchment (vector - polygon)

I'd be happy to use a contour layer (vector - line) to build the catchment from but I cannot find anything that will help me with that. Even if there was an AI I could train to do the delineation.

I hope that I am clear as to what I am after.

Thaks in advance.